Does there exist an entire function $f$ such that $f(z)+f(z^2)=z^3$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$?
Does there exist an entire function $f$ such that $f(z)+f(z^2)=z^3$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$?
This problem showed up on a qualifying exam; these exams enjoy including problems that utilize Liouville's theorem.
Method 1: Show $f$ is bounded and use Liouville
Here, I would suppose $f$ is entire and non-constant. If I can show that $f$ is bounded, I will have a contradiction which means that $f$ is constant.
Method 2: Use Taylor Expansion Since $f$ is entire, $f$ has a Taylor series expansion about $z=0$. Thus,
$$f(z) = f(0) + f'(0)z + \frac{f''(0)}{2}z^2 + \dots \tag{1}$$
By hypothesis,
$$f(z) = z^3-f(z^2) \tag{2}$$
But now, we can write
$$f(z^2) = f(0) + f'(0)z^2 + \frac{f''(0)}{2}z^4 + \dots \tag{3}$$
Then, rewriting $(2)$, we get
$$f(0) + f'(0)z + \frac{f''(0)}{2}z^2 + \dots = z^3 - (f(0) + f'(0)z^2 + \frac{f''(0)}{2}z^4 + \dots) \tag{4}$$
I seek to derive a contradiction here but I experience no such luck. I'm suspecting that the first method of showing $f$ is bounded might be a better bet. Any ideas?

There's $z^3-z^6+z^{12}-z^{24}\ldots$ but that has singularities along the unit circle.

Expanding on a comment of @Empy2: Since $f$ is entire expand it as
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n.$$
Then we have that
$$f(z^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^{2n}.$$
Using that $f(z)+f(z^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^{2n}=z^3$ and comparing coefficients you find that:
$$f(z)=z^3-z^6+z^{12}-z^{24}\ldots$$
which isn't entire.

@Sangchul Lee beat me to it. Gonna leave that here anyway. :)

I'm sorry, I can't quite see the result by comparing coefficients. With $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{2n}$, we get duplicates of every $a_n$. How can it be that subtracting them to the RHS causes them to vanish? Can you elaborate a little bit here?

Try it for the first couple of coefficients and see if you can find a pattern. For example you have that for $z^0$ that $a_0+a_0=0$, for $z^1$ that $a_1=0$, for $z^2$ that $a_2+a_1=0$, for $z^3$ that $a_3=1$ and so on....there is a little work here that I didn't include but you can find a pattern there.

Ah, okay. I see now. Thank you!

Expanding @Empy2's comment, suppose $f$ is an entire function that solves the given functional equation. Then by applying the equation twice,
$$ f(z) = z^3 - f(z^2) = z^3 - z^6 + f(z^4). $$
Recursively applying this relation, we get
$$ f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{2N-1} (-1)^k z^{3\cdot 2^k} + f(z^{4^N}). \tag{1}\label{e:1}$$
Also note that plugging $z = 0$ to the functional equation gives $f(0) = 0$. Hence, as $N \to \infty$, the right-hand side of the above identity converges to
$$ f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k z^{3\cdot 2^k}. $$
So by the uniqueness of power series, the right-hand side must be the power series expansion of $f(z)$ about $z = 0$. However, it is clear that the right-hand side has radius of convergence $R = 1$, a contradiction! For example,
$$ f(e^{2 \pi i/9}) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k e^{2^{k+1}\pi i/3} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1} + i\sqrt{3}}{2} $$
and this diverges.

Alternative solution. The last line suggests another solution: Plugging $z = e^{2\pi i/9}$ and $N = 6$ to $\eqref{e:1}$, we get
\begin{align*}
f(e^{2\pi i/9})
&= \sum_{k=0}^{11} (-1)^k e^{2^{k+1}\pi i/3} + f(z^{2^{13}\pi i/9}) \\
&= 6 i\sqrt{3} + f(e^{2\pi i/9}),
\end{align*}
a contradiction!

Should that limit have associated with it the assumption that $|z| < 1$? Great answer as always.

@CameronWilliams, That's a valid point! Let me clarify the logic that leads to the contradiction.

Clever and brutal answer! Thank you!!

A different approach: Show that $f$ grows at most as fast as a polynomial, and therefore is a polynomial.
Let
$$M(r)  = \max\{ |f(z)| : |r| \le r \}$$
be the maximum modulus function. Then
$$
 M(r^2) \le M(r) + r^3
$$
for all $r > 0$. In particular
$$
 M(2^2) \le M(2) + 2^3 \\
 M(2^4) \le M(2) + 2^3 + 2^{3 \cdot 2} \\
 M(2^8) \le M(2) + 2^3 + 2^{3 \cdot 4} + 2^{3 \cdot 8} 
$$
and generally:
$$
 M(2^{2^k}) \le M(2) + 2^3 + 2^{3 \cdot 4} + \cdots +  2^{3 \cdot 2^{k-1}} \\
\le M(2) + 1 + 2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^{3 \cdot 2^{k-1}} \\
= M(2) + 2 \cdot 2^{3 \cdot 2^{k-1}} - 1 \, .
$$
For arbitrary $r > 2$ we can choose $k$ such that $2^{2^{k-1}} \le r < 2^{2^k}$, then
$$
 M(r) \le  M(2^{2^k}) \le M(2) + 2 r^3
$$
which implies that $f$ is a polynomial (of degree at most $3$).
Finally, a simple comparison of the degrees shows that no polynomial can satisfy the identity $f(z^2) = z^3 - f(z)$.
In the same way one can (for example) show that if an entire function satisfies $f(z^k) = a f(z) + p(z)$ with an integer $k\ge 2$, a constant $a \ne 0$, and a polynomial $p$ then $f$ is a polynomial.
